# How to add atributes in Open LDAP?

Tags: openldap

It's my first time with LDAP, I want to import users from another LDAD (ldif file), but these have 3 attributes that I can not find in the objects of mine.

The attributes are:
roomNumber
associateNumber
memberOf

Viewing the old LDAP has an object called objectClass: inetOrgPerson, my question is how could I add this object to my LDAP without spoiling anything?

thank you very much for your attention.

Error example:

ERROR LDAP: error code 17 - associateNumber: attribute type undefined]
dn: uid=myuser,ou=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Just load the inetorgperson.schema into the server via the configuration.

Comment: I dont understand :(

Answer (score 0):

It's missing the inetorgperson schema on your ldap. You can see the installation details on the link [How To Configure OpenLDAP](http://beopensource.co.uk/?p=152)

Good lucky!!!